# html page looks different in actual than in chrome developer mode

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a website, I need it to support in all resolutions till 4k and  all browsers. For the same requirement, I have been using chrome developer mode, and have been testing my page in all resolutions. 
But my page is looking different in actual screen of the same resolution than the developer mode with that resolution.

Can any one please suggest what could be issue?

---

well.. when when I tried to test other websites on google chrome developer tool for responsive compatibility, I found that it was showing different result for other  website only.Perhaps I am not using it correctly, would appreciate greatly if anyone help with it. [image: Apple website on actual screen of 1280x800 resolution]

[image: Apple website on google chrome developer tool, tried to set 1280x800 resolution in developer tool]

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

try using something like the window resizer extension for a more accurate representation of how your webpage will look on certain screen sizes. Chrome is not always the most accurate.

Comment: thanks for the help Taylor! tried using window resizer extension even it does not show the exact result.. can you help with the most reliable extension for it to test on local?

Comment: hmm thats the one I use. are you using px/percent/em or rem?

Comment: using all actually.. but majorly using px for different breakpoints.. that is the requirement